# Generate and email coupon code to customer after they purchase full price item

Tags: ubercart

We have a situation where we want to be able to automate a process for certain customers to receive a discount coupon after making a purchase.

Ideally, customers could just throw two of whichever package they are purchasing into the cart and be good to go, but because of some oddities with our underlying product (a software package that they get access to for a few months) they need to make separate purchases if they need more than one license. And there are a few situations where we would want to provide a buy one get one half off coupon, but it's not every time.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a condition of some sort, like a particular coupon code or product that we can provide to customers, that once they purchase an email is automatically sent with a 50% off your next purchase coupon.

I'm pretty new to working with Drupal and don't know where to start with this or if it's even possible.

edit: we are working in Drupal 7 and using ubercart

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal just about anything is possible but you'll need to provide more context otherwise people won't answer you.

Drupal 7 or 8?
Are you using Commerce or Ubercart?

In any case, the Rules module might be what you are looking for. It has the ability to act on different events.

Comment: thanks! i edited my question to include those bits.

we are in drupal 7 using ubercart. so far, i haven't found anything in the rules module that would do this, but I may also be misunderstanding how it works.